# Explain yourself!

Tags: english-to-german

How do I say "Explain yourself!" like you do when you're mad at something someone has done and you're waiting for a good excuse.

1. > Erkläre dich!
2. > Erkläre dich selber!

Or is none of the above really idiomatic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Erkläre Dich" ist in der Tat in den meisten Fällen zu formal und auch ein salopperes "Erklär' Dich!" wird man heute kaum hören.

Dagegen ist ein "**Erklär's mir!**" heute durchaus gängig und m.E. sehr nahe am Original.

Dagegen wird "Was hast Du dir (nur) dabei gedacht?" oft als rhetorische Frage gebraucht, die gar keine Erklärung herausfordert, sondern nur tadeln will.

"Was soll das", wie LangLangC vorschlägt oder "Was sollte das?" ist, neben anderen Formulierungen, aber auch sehr üblich, je nach Kontext auch "Was war das (denn)?" oder spezifischer "Wieso hast Du das gemacht/getan/...?"

Comment: I never ever heard someone say "Erklär's mir" in this context. What region are you from?

Comment: Aus Moselfranken mit einer Mutter aus Ostpreußen, 4 Jahren in München, > 30 Jahre Berlin, davon 10 in Ostberlin aber überall ein eher hochdeutsch sprechendes Umfeld.

Answer (score 9):

I think most idiomatic would be

> Was hast Du dir (nur) dabei gedacht?

Literally: *What did you think about when you did this*

Answer (score 4):

[*Was soll das?*](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Was%20soll%20das%3F)

---

*Erkläre dich!* is fine, but very probably *too fine* (posh, or even now between archaic or anglicism): perceived as quite high-level register. An academic will respond with what you expect, a construction worker will laugh at you.

Answer (score 2):

> Wie kommst du dazu[, die Oma zu ohrfeigen]?

is a common demand for explanation.

> - Sag mir den Grund!
> - Sag mir warum!
> - Warum?!
> - Den Grund[ will ich wissen]!

Sayings like this are used especially if the first, less resolute attempt for an answer has failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also formulate it as a simple question, after stating the fact that should be explained. For maximum effect, this should be spoken in a stern, calm tone.

> Der Kuchen ist alle. Kannst du mir das erklären?

*The cake is gone. What is your explanation?*

Answer (score -2):

It depends a lot on the situation and on social context.

Your question ("being mad at somebody") sounds like you were imagining an everyday (private life) situation like somebody threw your laptop computer out of the window in the third floor. Typical reactions would be:

> He! Was soll das!
>
> Spinnst du?
>
> Bist du wahnsinnig geworden?
>
> Bist du verrückt geworden?
>
> Ich glaub' du spinnst. Laß das!
>
> Du bist wohl wahnsinnig!

Or if it is not the actual event, but rather considering it afterwards:

> Was hast du dir denn dabei gedacht?
>
> Spinnst du?
>
> Hast du dir irgendwas dabei gedacht?
>
> Was? Warum denn das?

(Well... good excuse for throwing someone's laptop out of the window... perhaps because the battery caught fire?)

But note that "being mad at somebody" is not an adequate reaction anyway, as it is in the same range of misbehaviour as the causing action, isn't it?

Comment: Die meisten Formen drücken nicht die Erwartung einer Erklärung aus. Ganz und gar nicht geht es hier um pädagogische Verhaltensempfehlungen.

Comment: Of course being mad at someone is an adequate reaction. If you take a sledgehammer and destroy my computer gear just because you felt like it, you can be damn sure I'll be mad at you. Furthermore, that is not even close to be in the same range of "misbehaviour".